# Proof negation in Gentzen system

Tags: logic, proof-writing, proof-theory

I am provided with the L¬ and R¬ Gentzen rules for negation (besides “Cut” rule and some  rules for ⋀ and →):

$${\Gamma\vdash\Delta,\varphi\over \Gamma,\lnot\varphi\vdash \Delta}\ L\lnot
\\[4ex]
{\Gamma,\varphi\vdash\Delta\over \Gamma\vdash\Delta\lnot\varphi}\ R\lnot
$$

I’m trying to proof:

$${\Gamma,\lnot\lnot q\vdash\Delta\over \Gamma,q\vdash \Delta}$$

However, I did not manage to this with the provided rules.

Does anyone have an idea of how to start?
Are there any other rule for negation in the Gentzen system that could be used here?

Answer (score 1):

We start a left branch with :

$$\frac{A \vdash A}{\lnot A, A \vdash}$$ by $\lnot$-left;

then :

$$\frac{\lnot A, A \vdash}{A \vdash \lnot \lnot A}$$ by $\lnot$-right.

Now we apply the *Cut rule* (where the cut-formula $\psi$ is $\lnot \lnot A$ ) :

> $$\frac {A \vdash \lnot \lnot A \quad \quad \Gamma, \lnot \lnot A \vdash \Delta } {\Gamma, A \vdash \Delta }$$

If we "merge" the derivation from the *Axiom* of the left top sequent, we obtain the "derived rule" :

> > $$\frac {\Gamma, \lnot \lnot A \vdash \Delta } {\Gamma, A \vdash \Delta }$$

Comment: I understand your explanation until the Cut rule.
Can I simply introduce a new sequent?

And how exactly did you apply this Cut rule, because as far as I know, the rule is of the form:

$\Gamma \vdash \Delta , q$  and  $\Gamma , q \vdash \Delta$  becomes  $\Gamma \vdash \Delta$. Did you take $q=\lnot \lnot A$ and $A$ (from the rule $A \vdash \lnot \lnot A$) as part of $\Gamma$ ?

Comment: @Alwin - I "introduce" it because it is the top sequent of the rule we have to prove. About the application of the *cut*, in your sistem it is "restricted" to *atomic* formulae ? Of course, I have applied it with $\lnot \lnot A$ taht is not atomic. Can you provide us withe the refernce to the textbook you are using, in order to check about the rules admitted ? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The textbook that I use is Mathematical Logic for Computer Science by Mordechai Ben-Ari. However, the teacher explained the system using a different notation than that is used in the book. In the book, the rules do not move formulae to the assumptions. The teacher, and I for my proof, use the Gentzen system in which the rules do move formulae to the assumptions. This are the rules as provided by the teacher: [link](http://nl.tinypic.com/r/107nhw1/8)

Comment: @Alwin - Ok, thanks. The $\psi$ in the *Cut rule* is a formula whatever; so, we can apply it with our $\lnot \lnot A$. When I introduce the sequent, I have only avoided the effort of writing the proof in tree-form; thin to the three initial sequents as the left branch and the "introduced" sequent as the single-formula right branch. The two are the the two top sequent of the cut.

Comment: Sorry, but how did you exactly com from an axiom to $\Gamma, \lnot \lnot A \vdash \Delta$ ?

If I do it similar as the previous one, I get this (which is not the same): $\Gamma, A \vdash A, \Delta $ --- Axiom    to   $\Gamma, \vdash A, \lnot A , \Delta$ --- by $\lnot$-right  to  $\Gamma, \lnot \lnot A \vdash A, \Delta$ --- by $\lnot$-left. I've got that additional A on the rightside.

Comment: @Alwin - I've reformatted it; I'm not able to write a unique derivation-tree, but I think now you can "see it" ...

Comment: Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @Alwin - the last point I want to stress is : have you understood that we have not proved a logical formula (like $\vdash \lnot \lnot A \rightarrow A$) but a "new" rule (a "derived" one) like : $\lor$-elim ?